# Как заполнить весь экран черным цветом с помощью js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
  document.body.onload = addElement;
  var my_div = newDiv = null;

  function addElement() {

    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.innerHTML = "<div style="background-color: black; width: 100%; height: 100%;"
> </div>";

    my_div = document.getElementById("org_div1");
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, my_div);
  }
```

Comment: document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black'

Answer (score 3):

С удалением содержимого страницы

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.body.innerHTML = "";
  document.body.style = "background-color: #000;";
});
```

Без удаления содержимого / Перекрытие содержимого div'ом

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style = "position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#000;";
  document.body.append(div);   
});
```

Comment: Для второго я бы лучше использовал свойство inset для краткости и fixed и ещё z-index + нужно скрыть скролл на body, если есть.
  ```let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style = "position:fixed;inset: 0; z-index: 2147483647; background-color:#000;";
  document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  document.body.append(div);```

Comment: ну, и если прям весь экран, то .requestFullscreen() нужен